# How to use paid asset from the Asset Store in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to install a paid asset from the Unity Asset Store. When I click Buy the button goes from "Buy $5.00" (see image below) to "Please Wait" (see image below), and then back to "Buy $5.00" and nothing happens.

Before clicking:

[image]

After clicking:

[image]

Has anyone ran into this issue or know how to fix it? How to I put funds into my Unity account?

Comment: I get this issue occasionally. It's a Unity Store issue, and triggers errors in the Unity console. The fix for me usually is to just restart Unity and try again.

Comment: Thanks, yes it looks like it was an intermittent issue, I am now seeing shopping cart dialog when clicking the button.

Answer (score -1):

You should login to Asset Store first. Open *Asset Store* from *Windows Menu*.

In Assets Store Pop-up, on Right Top side, Create account/Login, do confirmation from your email & then Start Purchasing.

Secondly, You do not need to transfer funds to any unity account. Its direct bank to bank transaction using Card. See pic Below.

Hope this helps!!
[image]